# Range validator for multiple types

Tags: validation, generics, interval, kotlin, type-safety

I have an existing overloaded set of functions that I cannot change and need to be tested:

```
object Validator {
    fun validateRange(min: Int, max: Int): Boolean = true
    fun validateRange(min: Long, max: Long): Boolean = true
    fun validateRange(min: Double, max: Double): Boolean = true
    fun validateRange(min: String, max: String): Boolean = true

    fun validateRangeInput(min: Int, max: Int, input: Int): Boolean = true
    fun validateRangeInput(min: Long, max: Long, input: Long): Boolean = true
    fun validateRangeInput(min: Double, max: Double, input: Double): Boolean = true
    fun validateRangeInput(min: String, max: String, input: String): Boolean = true
}
```

The test data for `validateRange()` contain each of the various types. Here is a sample of the input data:

```
val inputs = listOf(
        Pair("1", "1"),
        Pair(1, 1),
        Pair(1L, 1L),
        Pair(1.0, 1.0)
)
```

Of course, I cannot simply do this:

```
inputs.forEach { (min, max) -> Validator.validateRange(min, max) }
```

My current solution implements a helper using generics and a `when` block with the `is` operator and smart casting:

```
fun <T> validateRangeHelper(min: T, max: T): Boolean {
    return when {
        min is Int && max is Int -> Validator.validateRange(min, max)
        min is Long && max is Long -> Validator.validateRange(min, max)
        min is Double && max is Double -> Validator.validateRange(min, max)
        min is String && max is String -> Validator.validateRange(min, max)
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}

inputs.forEach { (a, b) -> validateRangeHelper(a, b) }
```

This approach grows cumbersome with each additional argument, such as for the `validateRangeInput()` functions.

```
fun <T> validateRangeHelper(min: T, max: T, input: T): Boolean {
    return when {
        min is Int && max is Int && input is Int -> Validator.validateRangeInput(min, max, input)
        min is Long && max is Long && input is Long -> Validator.validateRangeInput(min, max, input)
        min is Double && max is Double && input is Double -> Validator.validateRangeInput(min, max, input)
        min is String && max is String && input is String -> Validator.validateRangeInput(min, max, input)
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can improve the helper or avoid it all together without changing `Validator`?

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need more context. Can you provide the real code please? It's off-topic otherwise.

Comment: @t3chb0t thanks for the request, I have added more context.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not one of my proudest answers...
You can delegate the work of casting to another function

```
fun <T> Pair<*,*>.validate2(lambda: (T, T)->Boolean) = lambda(first as T, second as T)
```

In your `validateHelperclass` you can call this function:

```
fun <T> validateRangeHelper(pair: Pair<T,T>): Boolean = when(pair.first) {
    is Int -> pair.validate3<Int>(Validator::validateRange)
    is Double -> pair.validate3<Double>(Validator::validateRange)
    is Long -> pair.validate3<Long>(Validator::validateRange)
    is String -> pair.validate3<String>(Validator::validateRange)
    else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
}
```

(I called it `validate2`, as I created a custom class which has more than 2 parameters, such that I could test both the methods, based on  if i called `validate2` or `validate3`...)

## typeunsafe

```
//just to be able to get three
class TestValues<T : Any>(
    val min: T,
    val max: T,
    val input: T
)
```

I search the functions with a certain name and parameter count. I extracted it from a function, but of course you can type the name yourself. Note, you have to import `kotlin.reflect.KFunction2`.

```
inline fun <reified R : Any> createTester2WithInt(obj: R, f: KFunction2<Int, Int, Boolean>) =
    Tester2(
        obj,
        R::class.findMethodsWithType(f.name, 2)
    )

inline fun <reified R : Any> createTester3WithInt(obj: R, f: KFunction3<Int, Int, Int, Boolean>) =
    Tester3(
        obj,
        R::class.findMethodsWithType(f.name, 3)
    )

open class Tester(
    private val obj: Any,
    private val map: Map<KClass<out Any>, KFunction<Any?>>
) {
    @PublishedApi // means you shouldn't call it by yourself
    internal inline fun <reified T, reified S : Any> call(vararg args: S, clazz: KClass<out S>): T {
        val method = map[clazz] ?: throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException()
        return method.call(obj, *args) as T
    }
}

class Tester2(obj: Any, map: Map<KClass<out Any>, KFunction<Any?>>) : Tester(obj, map) {
    inline fun <reified T, reified S : Any> test(first: S, second: S): T = call(first, second, clazz = first::class)
}

class Tester3(obj: Any, map: Map<KClass<out Any>, KFunction<Any?>>) : Tester(obj, map) {
    inline fun <reified T, reified S : Any> test(first: S, second: S, third: S): T = call(first, second, third, clazz = first::class)
}

fun <R : Any> KClass<out R>.findMethodsWithType(
    name: String,
    parameterCount: Int
) = memberFunctions.asSequence()
    .filter { it.name == name }
    //the returnType is also a parameter
    .filter { it.parameters.size == parameterCount + 1 }
    .filter { it.returnType.jvmErasure == Boolean::class }
    .filter {
        val paramTypes = it.javaMethod!!.parameterTypes
        paramTypes[0] == paramTypes[1]
    }.associateBy { it.javaMethod!!.parameterTypes[0].kotlin }


fun create2Pred(pred: (Any, Any) -> Boolean) = pred


fun main() {
    val validator2 = createTester2WithInt<Validator>(Validator, Validator::validateRange)
    val validator3 = createTester3WithInt<Validator>(Validator, Validator::validateRangeInput)
    val list = listOf(
        TestValues(1, 1, 1),
        TestValues(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        TestValues("1", "1", "1")
    ).forEach {
        val a: Boolean = validator2.test(it.min, it.max)
        val b: Boolean = validator3.test(it.min, it.max, it.input)
        println("$a and $b")
    }
}


object Validator {
    fun validateRange(min: Int, max: Int): Boolean = true
    fun validateRange(min: Long, max: Long): Boolean = true
    fun validateRange(min: Double, max: Double): Boolean = true
    fun validateRange(min: String, max: String): Boolean = true

    fun validateRangeInput(min: Int, max: Int, input: Int): Boolean = true
    fun validateRangeInput(min: Long, max: Long, input: Long): Boolean = true
    fun validateRangeInput(min: Double, max: Double, input: Double): Boolean = true
    fun validateRangeInput(min: String, max: String, input: String): Boolean = true
}
```